# if $(a,b,c)$ is a Pythagorean triple then $a$ or $b$ or $c$ can be divided by 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Prove that if $(a,b,c)$ is a Pythagorean triple then $a$ or $b$ or $c$ can be divided by 3

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: What does this even mean?

Comment: if(a,b,c) was a  Pythagorean triple  then a or b or c can be divided by 3

Comment: There seems to be some translation issues here.  If you need assistance translating your question into English, that is fine.  Label the question with the tag (translation request) and someone who knows both English and your language will hopefully be able to help.  As it stands, it is incredibly unclear what it is you are asking.

Comment: it's clear now ?!

Comment: For future reference as well, you are expected to show at least some semblance of an attempt and your own thoughts on the problem.  Otherwise all you will get are hints.  What do you know about pythagorean triples?  What do you know about squares modulo three?  Proof by contradiction?

Comment: ok. i will, thanks

Comment: My answer doesn't rely on anything complex such as $x^2 \equiv 0$ or $1$ $\mod 3$ or any "known" (not by everyone (just by a few)) statement such as "the perfect squares$ \mod 3$ are $0$ and $1$". I proved everything, even an elementary student would understand. I think you got "on hold" because of "appropriate to your experience level" part. But is clear that any one that can formulate that question can understand my approach :)

Answer (score 4):

We know that $a^2+b^2=c^2$, and that the perfect squares mod $3$ are $0$ and $1$. Therefore $c^2$ is *not* $2$ mod $3$, and so it's not the case that both $a^2$ and $b^2$ are $1$ mod $3$. Therefore one of them is $0$ mod $3$. Let it be $a^2$. Then $a$ is also $0$ mod $3$ because $1^2=2^2=1\pmod{3}$. So $3|a$.

Comment: thanks a lot. i think this solve my question

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*: $$x^2\equiv \text{0 or 1}\pmod3$$

Comment: basic  Pythagorean triple is ( 2n+1, 2n(n+1), 2n(n+1)+1) .. so i think i most prove one of this is can divided by 3. 
it's easy to see that 2n(n+1) can divided b 4

Answer (score 0):

$$
(3k)^2 = 3k' \; , (3k+1)^2 = 3k'+1  \; and \; (3k+2)^2 = 3k'+4=3k''+1
$$
(so there's no square of the form $3k + 2$)

If $a = 3k$ or $b=3k$ we are done, assume the opposite:

$a\mod3 \neq b \mod 3 \neq 0$
$$
(3m+1)^2+(3n+2)^2 = 3p+1+4=3p'+2 = c^2
$$
(not possible)

$a\mod3 = b \mod 3 \neq 0 $
$$
(3m+1)^2+(3n+1)^2 = 3p+1+1=3p'+2 = c^2
$$
$$
(3m+2)^2+(3n+2)^2 = 3p+4+4=3p'+2 = c^2
$$
(not possible)

So at least one must be divisible by 3